# BWA: Detecting Variation in Short-Read Sequences

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genome, bam

I used the Burrows-Wheeler Aligner to map a high-coverage short-read sequence to a reference genome. The output is in .sam format. I have also used a *separate program* to identify the loci in the *reference genome* at which microsatellites occur. I would like to identify all the loci in the *short-read sequence* at which the microsatellite length and loci *differ* from the reference genome. Does anyone know any tools or packages I could use to read a .sam/.bam file of a short-read sequence mapped to a reference genome and identify specific loci at which the short-read sequence differs from the reference genome? I am using RStudio and have access to my university's supercomputer clusters.

For info on microsatellites, see here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite#:~:text=A%20microsatellite%20is%20a%20tract,locations%20within%20an%20organism's%20genome.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite#:%7E:text=A%20microsatellite%20is%20a%20tract,locations%20within%20an%20organism%27s%20genome.)

Comment: suggest you try https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ seems extremely specific...

Comment: there are packages for reading bam files, for example https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicAlignments.html or other packages in Bioconductor. but your question of how to find differences... that is a total mystery to me because i don't know what they are

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf ! I have re-posted the question to bioinformatics.stackexchange and will check out bioconductor